# Button во flipper. Ошибка Could not find method getResultQuad(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать приложение при помощи flipper. Итак при нажатию на кнопку выводит следующую ошибку:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method getResultQuad(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'getResult'
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17446)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Вот сам код:

```
public class QuadEquation extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button getResult;

    public void QuadDiffer() {

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        EditText koefA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koefA);
        EditText koefB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koefB);
        EditText koefC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.koefC);

        int a = Integer.parseInt(koefA.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(koefB.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(koefC.getText().toString());
        int diskrim = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (diskrim < 0) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Дискриминант < 0. Корни отсутствуют", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        } else {
            double x1 = (double) (-b + Math.sqrt(diskrim) / 2 * a);
            double x2 = (double) (-b - Math.sqrt(diskrim) / 2 * a);
            result.setText("x1 = " + x1 + "and x2 = " + x2);
        }
        getResult.findViewById(R.id.result);
        getResult.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        QuadDiffer();
    }
}
```

---

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements` View.OnTouchListener {
ViewFlipper flipper;
float fromPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int [] layouts = new int[] {R.layout.quad_activity, R.layout.calc_activity, R.layout.third_activity};
       for(int layout : layouts)
       {
           flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
       }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            fromPosition = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float toPosition = event.getX();
            if(fromPosition > toPosition)
             {
                 flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.go_next_in));
                 flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.go_next_out));
                 flipper.showNext();
             }
            else if (fromPosition < toPosition)
             {
                 flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.go_prev_in));
                 flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.go_prev_out));
                 flipper.showPrevious();
             }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/koefA"
    android:hint="Enter here first koef"
    android:layout_above="@+id/koefB"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/koefB"
    android:hint="Enter here second koef"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/koefC"
    android:hint="Enter here third koef"
    android:layout_below="@+id/koefB"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Result"
    android:id="@+id/getResult"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/koefB"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="getResultQuad"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_below="@+id/koefC"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Main XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас onClick выставлен в XML. Никогда так не делайте. Ваша ошибка возникла именно из за этого.
2. В поле `Button getResult;` никогда ничего не записывается, но при этом вы его пытаетесь использовать:

   ```
   getResult.findViewById(R.id.result); 
   getResult.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
3. Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что метод `getResultQuad(View)` не найден. Это происходит потому, что в разметке выставлен `onClick` :

   ```
   android:onClick="getResultQuad"
   ```